# Ionic 3 Image lazy loader

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, image-processing, ionic3

I am developing ionic application which uses external image files. These images are loading in elements such as ion-card,ion-item,ion-slides. I need a spinner or some kind of technique to show until the image successfully.

I tried image caching plugins but it wasn't success.

Looking forward a better solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a loading picture in your js e.g.

```
loadingAnimation = "../../assets/img/loadingAnimation.gif";
```

Then use the || operator when setting the source in html:

```
<img [src]='{{ (yourActualPicture) || (loadingAnimation ) }}'/>
```

This way the loading animation will be shown until the actual picture has been downloaded.

On a side-note: You might want to have a look at Ionic's *Spinner* component
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/spinner/Spinner/

Comment: Thank you.Yes this works. Currently i am having this technique using spinner. But the issue occurs when actual image loads top to bottom. Anyway big thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**You can achieve this problem show until the image successfully using Ionic Image Loader**

**FIRST PROCESS**

Ionic Module that loads images in a background thread and caches them for later use. Uses HttpClient from Angular 4+, and cordova-plugin-file via ionic-native wrappers.

**Installation**

**1. Install the NPM Package**

```
npm install --save ionic-image-loader
```

**2. Install Required Plugins**

```
npm i --save @ionic-native/file
```

**ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
3. Import IonicImageLoader module**
**Add IonicImageLoader.forRoot() in your app's root module**

```
import { IonicImageLoader } from 'ionic-image-loader';

// import the module
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    IonicImageLoader.forRoot()
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Then add IonicImageLoader in your child/shared module(s)**

```
import { IonicImageLoader } from 'ionic-image-loader';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    IonicImageLoader
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

**Uses**

This HTML code demonstrates basic usage of this module:

```
<img-loader src="https://path.to/my/image.jpg"></img-loader>
```

By default, the module sets the image as the background of the  element. If you want the module to use the image as an  tag inside the  elemen, just add useImg attribute as shown below:

```
<img-loader src="https://path.to/my/image.jpg" useImg></img-loader>
```

You can also listen to the load event to be notified when the image has been loaded:

```
<img-loader src="path/to/image" (load)="onImageLoad($event)></img-loader>

import { ImgLoader } from 'ionic-image-loader';

...

onImageLoad(imgLoader: ImgLoader) {
  // do something with the loader
}
```

**More Details visit this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-image-loader)**

**SECOND PROCESS**

**Define a loading picture in `.ts`**

```
defaultImage: string = "assets/img/animationImage.png";
```

**Then use the Logical or `||` operator in `.html`**

```
<img  src="{{ your image || defaultImage}}" />
```

Comment: I tried the both methods. But in the first method it does not show the spinner until the image loads. Second method works fine but when actual image renders it loads top to bottom. Anyway Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome I tried both method it's work fine to me .. anyway if its solve then good but if not then share code

Comment: I tried with a new project too. but the spinner is not showing. I tried global configuration also. caching part works fine. but no spinners. Can you please share your configurations